# Adobe Wave Install on Startup

Tags: macos

Every time I start up my computer an Adobe Wave installer launches. IT's quite frustrating, how do I remove this?

I have tried both canceling and completing the install process, no matter what it will be there next time.

I also can not find any application files on my computer for Adobe Weave.

This is on Mac OS/X.

Thanks.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but what is Adobe Weave? This page is the first hit on google and the next one refers to a type of carpet?

Comment: Ooops, it's called Adobe Wave. That could be why I was having so much difficulty finding information about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, missed the tag completely.

Ok then; go to **System Preferences** > **Accounts** > your account, click on the **Login Items** tab and see if Adobe Weave is there. If it is, remove it.

Comment: Sorry should have added it to the body of the post, not just a tag, this is on Mac.

Comment: Found it there, give me a little while before I can restart to test....

Comment: Ok, let me know if it works :)

Comment: Appears to have fixed it! Thanks so much, forgot all about Login Items screen.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!